# pyspark optimization tip - Jaccard score

Tags: python, lambda, pyspark, sparse-matrix

I am trying to create item:item similarity sparse matrix in pyspark (using Jaccard). I have a product input file that looks like following:

```
{"LEVEL2_NM": "Lvl2", "product_index": 1, "LEVEL3_NM": "Lvl3_Nm_1", "LEVEL2_CD": "10001", "ATTRIBUTES": {"COLOR": ["Red", "Blue"], "SEASON": null, "BRAND": "Nike", "NEW_COLOR_CD": ["01", "02"]}}

{"LEVEL2_NM": "Lvl2", "product_index": 2, "LEVEL3_NM": "Lvl3_Nm_2", "LEVEL2_CD": "10001", "ATTRIBUTES": {"COLOR": ["Red", "Green"], "SEASON": null, "BRAND": "Adidas", "NEW_COLOR_CD": ["01", "03"]}}
```

The file is about 200MB big. And the final output should like the following:

```
[1 , [3, 0.42], [5,0.2].....]
[2 , [6, 0.71], [8, 0.3].... 
...
...
```

I have written the following piece of pyspark code, which is running alright for a subset of the data (~10K), but when I try to execute it for 2M records, it runs forever.

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
import json
import itertools



conf = SparkConf().setMaster("local[4]").setAppName("ProductMatrix")
sc = SparkContext(conf = conf)
lines = sc.textFile("/..../product.txt")

def parseJsonLineMap(line):
    jsonVal = json.loads(line)
    return (str(jsonVal['LEVEL2_NM']),[str(jsonVal['product_index']), str(jsonVal['ATTRIBUTES']['SEASON']), str(jsonVal['ATTRIBUTES']['BRAND'])])

def jaccard_sim(p,q):
    return float(len(set(p) & set(q)))/len(set(p) | set(q))


def jaccard_dict(p,q):
    p1 = p.keys()
    q1 = q.keys()
    pq_intersect = set(p1) & set(q1)
    deno = len(pq_intersect)
    nume = 0.0
    for i in pq_intersect:
        if type(p[i]) is list:
            nume = nume + jaccard_sim(p[i],q[i])
        else:
            nume = nume + jaccard_sim([p[i]],[q[i]])
    final_jaccard = nume/deno
    return final_jaccard

rdd0 = lines.map(parseJsonLineMap)
#rdd1 = rdd0.partitionBy(100).persist()
rdd1 = rdd0.partitionBy(100, (lambda x: int(x[0]))).persist()

rdd2 = rdd1.join(rdd1)
rdd3 = rdd2.filter(lambda x: x[1][0][0] <= x[1][1][0])
rdd4 = rdd3.map(lambda x : [  x[1][0][0] , {x[1][1][0] : str(jaccard_dict(x[1][0][1], x[1][1][1]))}])
rdd5 = rdd4.reduceByKey(lambda x,y : {**x , **y}).map(lambda x: json.dumps({x[0]:x[1]}))
rdd5.saveAsTextFile(out_file)
```

Comment: Can you explain a bit on how to get output and what does the output means? e.g. what is `[1, [3, 0.42], [5,0.2], ...]` ? I'd imagine that you can create full table of pairs that you're interested in and apply jaccard distance in one time.

Comment: Hi @titipata, goal is to create a sparse matrix of the co-relation between all the products. So, if there are m products it will be m x m matrix. Now, for sparse, we do not really need to maintain 0 values, and instead have a RowMatrix Vector structure like the one I have provided. So, to illustrate the 2 rows of example, it means the following -  matrix[1,3] = 0.42, matrix[1,5] = 0.2, matrix[2,6] = 0.71 and so on...

Comment: And Jaccard distance is calculated between which features in this case? Sorry for asking very detail questions. Trying to see if I can solve it :)

Comment: Not a problem at all - Jaccard distance is being calculated on the product attributes given above namely, COLOR, SEASON and BRAND. Sorry for the late reply.